# How to add expand and collapse option in the table cell in fitnesse

Tags: java, expand, fitnesse, tablecell, wiki-markup

I'm working on automation tool which uses fitnesse tool to get the data and compare. My table has all the data and i've the fixture to take that data and process and return the results. If the case is pass i show just pass but if the case is failed, i've to show more information in the table cell. I want to show the failure content in the expand and collapse view. Can i add expand and collapse view in a cell of a table in fitnesse? I tried to add but the wiki markup syntax is getting disturbed if i add or the expand / collapse view is coming out of table and showing separately. Can i include the expand / collapse view in the table cell?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a collapsible section inside a cell using the "nesting" markup: !( and )!

Example:

```
|cell|!(nested
!*> collapsible
line
line
line
*!
content)!|cell|
```